# Simplistic time tracking application

Tags: osx, time-management

I am looking for a time tracking application which is used primarily for personal interest, not billing, so 100% accuracy is not as important.

The features I would like:

- List of projects
- "Quick add" buttons for time

  - Ideally able to "undo" or edit somehow?
- Summaries of daily/weekly/monthly totals

  - Ideally with access to historical data

It can be either a webapp or standalone app. Otherwise, that's pretty much it. I am not as concerned with everything adding to X hours a day/week. IE if I hit "add 30 min" or something 100x a day I'm fine if it shows 50 hours/day.

An interface something like this would be perfect:

[image]

The key is simplicity in adding time to a project. Bonus points if it works natively with Pomodoro timeboxing.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Fanurio](http://www.fanuriotimetracking.com):

- Although it can also be used for billing, you can disable the billing module to track time for personal activities.
- You can manage a list of projects and set a due date for each project.
- You add and edit the time you record on each project.
- It has time reports that allow you to analyze historical data.
- It doesn't have a Pomodoro module.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Toggl](https://www.toggl.com/) since 2011 and I'm quite happy with it - and it's free.

You can obtain infos by project / labels, by specific ranges of time... and has team functionalities + billing (on the paid version, just in case you change your mind).

Answer (score -1):

I use MoneyPenny.me and can recommend it to you  https://moneypenny.me/en/tour-the-app/time-tracking

You can log worked hours on different projects or use time tracker.
Then in report section you choose time range, projects clients etc for clear summary https://moneypenny.me/en/tour-the-app/reports

Comment: This looks like most of the many "standard" tracking apps out there that don't have simple functionality that I am looking for.